# using pop on multidimensional lists python with dynamoDB

Tags: python, lambda, aws-lambda, logic

I want to pop an item from a list of lists.
So I have a scan for all dynamo Items and want to "pop" one field from each list.

For example:

```
 response = table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('userId').eq(userId)
        )
        
        agentList = response['Items']
```

The List:

```
  "result": [
    {
      "credentials": {
        "key": "xxx",
        "secret": "xxxx"
      },
      "active": true,
      "totalImported": "12345",
     }]
```

From this example, I have a bunch of Results and for every result list, I will remove the Item "credentials" like

```
agentList.pop('credentials')
```

However, this isn't working

Comment: Can you maybe explain what exactly isn't working? Do you receive an error? If yes, can you paste the error message here? If not, can you paste the expected and actual output?

Comment: When I do as follows:

`agentList = response['Items']
  agentList.pop('credentials', None)`

This is the result => "Error: pop expected at most 1 argument, got 2."

When I do this: 
`agentList = response['Items']
  agentList.pop('credentials')`

This is the result => "Error: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer."

In a single Call from database, the pop is working, also with the string "credentials"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the `pop()` on a list. So, you can specify a position in the list, but, as a list has no key values, you can't use a string. Hence the error.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but, assuming you want to remove the 'credentials' from every item in the list you could do something like:

```
agentList = [
    {
        "credentials": {
            "key": "xxx",
            "secret": "xxxx"
        },
        "active": True,
        "totalImported": "12345",
    },
    {
        "credentials": {
            "key": "yyy",
            "secret": "yyy"
        },
        "active": True,
        "totalImported": "2222",
    }
]

for result in agentList:
    result.pop('credentials')

print(agentList)
```

Which would result in:

```
[{'active': True, 'totalImported': '12345'}, {'active': True, 'totalImported': '2222'}]
```

Comment: Should work too!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this way:

```
print(items)
    
    agentList =[]
    
    for result in items['Items']:
        agentList.append(result)
        result.pop('credentials')
```

Appending the List each by each and afterwards "popping" the "credentials" field.